# How can I get user details by UID after login with React and Firestore?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here I'm taking all the docs from Firestore:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
        const data = await getDocs(usersCollectionRef);
        setUsers(data.docs.map((doc) => ({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id,
        })))
    };
    getUsers();
}, []);
```

Then I put it on the following div to show the details:

```
                     <div>
                    {users.map((user) => {
                        return (<div className="card-body" key={user.id}>
                            <p className="card-text"><u>User details</u></p>
                            <p className='card-text'>User : {user.id}</p>
                            <p className='card-text'>User : {user.name}</p>
                            <p className='card-text'>Your weight : {user.weight}</p>
                            <p className='card-text'>Your height : {user.height}</p>
                            <p className='card-text'>Age : {user.age}</p>
                        </div>)
                    })}
                </div>
```

It shows all the documents of all the users if there is more than 1 user in the Firestore DB:
[On the below image you can see the details of both user that is stored in the DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVtdD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching all documents from the collection using `getDocs(collectionRef)`. If you want to fetch current user's document only then you can use `getDoc()` with a `DocumentReference` instead as shown below:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      const uid = user.uid;
      const snapshot = await getDoc(doc(db, "users", uid));
      if (snapshot.exists()) {
        setUser(snapshot.data())
      } else {
        console.log("User doc missing")
      }
    } else {
      console.log("User not logged in")
      setUser(null);
    }
  });
}, []);
```

Then you don't have to use `map` as `user` is not an array:

```
  <div>
    {true ? (
      <div className="card-body" key={user.id}>
        <p className="card-text">
          <u>User details</u>
        </p>
        <p className="card-text">User : {user.id}</p>
        <p className="card-text">User : {user.name}</p>
        <p className="card-text">Your weight : {user.weight}</p>
        <p className="card-text">Your height : {user.height}</p>
        <p className="card-text">Age : {user.age}</p>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <p>No user logged in</p>
    )}
  </div>
```